# Windows 7 SSD Tweaks inside VMWare Fusion

Tags: windows-7, ssd, vmware-fusion

There are a number of resources out there showing how you should 'Setup' Windows 7 when using a SSD (disable defrag, superfetch, etc.), but is there anything you should do if running Windows 7 inside VMWare Fusion on a SSD?

I guess there are two instances here

- Running VMWare Inside a Virtual Drive
- Running VMWare accessing a Boot Camp Partition

I'm concerned with the first item right now, but may possibly move to a Boot Camp partition if performance does not increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do the same things.  The objective is to prevent excessive/unnecessary writes to the SSD, whether the guest is using the drive directly (Boot Camp) or though an intermediary layer (VMDK/VHD).

> possibly move to a Boot Camp partition if performance does not increase.

Performance for what?  What are you expecting to do?

Comment: Performance is for using this for Development/Visual Studio 2010

Comment: An SSD should help that out quite a bit.  Giving your guest VM enough RAM is also important, which of course requires your host having that kind of RAM to spare.